# joda DateTime timezone

Tags: date, datetime, jodatime

Can someone please explain to me how joda DateTime time zone works? I have :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTime utc = new DateTime(new Date()).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
    DateTime nonUtc = new DateTime(new Date());
    long l = DateTimeZone.UTC.convertLocalToUTC(new Date().getTime(), false);
    DateTime converted = new DateTime(l);

    System.out.println("UTC :"+utc.toDate() + " , time zone :"+utc.getZone().getID());
    System.out.println("Non UTC :"+nonUtc.toDate()+ " , time zone :"+nonUtc.getZone().getID());
    System.out.println("Converted :"+converted.toDate()+ " , time zone :"+converted.getZone().getID());
}
```

The output of this is below. Local default timezone is Europe/Athens

```
UTC :Thu Sep 03 10:40:30 EEST 2015 , time zone :UTC
Non UTC :Thu Sep 03 10:40:30 EEST 2015 , time zone :Europe/Athens
Converted :Thu Sep 03 10:40:30 EEST 2015 , time zone :Europe/Athens
```

I can understand that the first one creates a `new Date()` in UTC with time from my default TZ, the second one creates a `new Date()` with default TZ, but why doesn't the last row convert local time to UTC?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should not try to use [DateTimeZone.convertLocalToUTC()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#convertLocalToUTC(long,%20boolean)). It is rather useful for framework-internal timezone calculations. I advise against the usage of this method for any other use-case because its signature is extremely confusing. The long-argument is intended to be a *local instant* per API. But instants are usually meant as absolute global instants in context of most date-time-libraries (even in Joda-Time if you look at its class `Instant`). Another important reason: Looking at a long-parameter cannot tell us if this is a local or a global parameter (the type `long` does not transport this information). You always need context to decide if local or global here.

Now the real core of your "problem". **Your input to this method is not local, but just a global instant (using `new Date().getTime()`) hence no real conversion happens.** And the following line `new DateTime(l);` will still use your default timezone based on the same global instant.